# Google Analytics tracking and Goal tracking for asynchrounous call back

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, analytics

I have a Simple contact us page for which i want to set Goals.

I can track Goals if i have tow files like

When one Contact.aspx page and Contact-Thank-You.aspx page.

But my problems is that i am saving the changes using Update Panel for Asynchronous post back and thanks you message is displayed on the same page after users message is successfully posted. during this process URL never changes so tracking Goals is not possible.

Is their a way i can track goals for Asynchronous postback even if we have just one URL.

`http://www.abc.com/Contact.aspx`

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the [`trackPageview`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) method in `ga.js` manually after making the ajax call. You can specify any url you want while calling `trackPageview`. So track `Contact-ThankYou.aspx` with `trackPageview` manually and the goal will be tracked.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Contact-ThankYou.aspx']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is true for Classic Analytics.

If questioner is using Universal Analytics, the syntax for this would be:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/Contact-ThankYou.aspx');
```

Checking for Classic or Universal, look for ga.js or analytics.js. ga.js is Classic and analytics.js is the newer Universal Analytics.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding)